# When did the Jews/Christians go wrong?

Tags: christianity, jews

It is my understanding that the reason God needed to deliver a teaching to Mohammed in the first place is because the Jews and Christians irredeemably strayed from the teachings of Moses and Jesus.

Does Islam have an opinion on approximately when

- The Jews strayed from Moses
- The Jews strayed from Jesus
- The Christians strayed from Jesus

to the extent that another prophet was needed?

Comment: ***It is my understanding that the reason God needed to deliver a teaching to Mohammed in the first place is because the Jews and Christians irredeemably strayed from the teachings of Moses and Jesus.***  I am not sure that this is correct. Islamic belief holds that Muhammad was Abraham's supplication for his son Ishmael, also that he was prophesied in the Torah and promised by Jesus as his successor: part of the Messianic promise. As such he was part of the plan and not a reaction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is one of the things that is thoroughly explained in Quran, in many verses.

To make it short, both absolutely went wrong when they denied the prophet Muhammad as a prophet, since both Jews and Christians teachings has told that there was to be another prophet coming. This has already indicated that their teaching was not yet complete until the final prophet has come. So, in other words, the prophet Muhammad was sent as a prophecy not because the Jews and Christians went wrong, but because the teaching was not yet complete.

If they hadn't denied the prophet Muhammad when he came, certainly they would be forgiven of previous wrongdoings. Two notable examples of each wrongdoings and hence gives a vague start of when they turned wrong:

- Jews killing the prophets that they denied (QS 2:87, 2:61). This could be easily looked up of which prophets they killed. And the reasoning is also explained in Quran is being arrogant, and out of the limits of the limits.
- Christians denies that there is only one God (major shirk) and made others to be equal as Allah. (QS 4:171, 5:72-75, 5:116, 19:88-93)

Reference:

- http://muslimpath.com/english/index.php?page=meeladdet23
- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam_and_antisemitism
- https://en.m.wikiquote.org/wiki/Qur%27an_on_Christianity

Comment: I know of Jewish prophecy that speaks of a prophet to come (e.g. Devarim 19:15). To which Christian teaching(s) are you referring? The muslimpath.com page only refers to biographies of Muhammad and historical accounts of individuals who said that he was the predicted prophet. Can you give references to actual teachings?

Comment: @mojo unfortunately I am not too intimate with details of Christian teachings, hence I can't give you details for the moment. I am aware though that Christian teachings are based on Jewish scriptures. So, it should refer to the same scripture that speaks of a prophet to come. The muslimpath.com refers to one instance that a Christian monk (which I would assume understands Christian's teaching) recognizes the signs of a prophet from his scriptures, so that should be an indication that there is such teaching in Christian. In any case, the OP did asked from Islam's perspective.

Comment: I was only asking about the claim—if there were details. The personal beliefs of individuals is not as forceful of an argument as information from the sources they claim to be divine.

Comment: @mojo Classic works usually cite the *paracelete* as referring to Muhammad, some argue using the hebrew translation *menahem*.

Comment: the jews knew a prophet was coming! They rejected the Prophet Muhammad sallalahu alaihi wa sallam due to their arrogance in fact which was so ironic

Comment: @mojo (and others) the correct reference is Devarim (Deuteronomy) 18:15, and this reference to an **Israelite** prophet, not an Ishmaelite, which Muhammad is. So he can't fulfill this prophecy. Additionally, Christian teaching and Scripture strongly implicates Jesus as the fulfillment of that prophecy, not needing any other. Finally, the paraclete is certainly not Muhammad or any other human nor can it be, as Jesus said of the Comfortor (Holy Spirit, paraclete), "he will be with you **forever**" and that the paraclete will be with all believers (at the same time), and thus can't be human.

Answer (score -1):

If you read Quran, it is mentioned that Jews go wrong when they disbelieved in Jesus Christ (pbuh) and they still think that Jesus didn’t came to them and they think that Jesus will come one day, and as for Christians, they disbelieved when they committed shirk. And when Jews heard that prophet Muhammad will come, they tried to harm him when he was young according to Quran.

And that is how People of Book go wrong.

If you see something wrong, you have the right to edit my answer.

Answer (score -1):

#### "(...) Christians irredeemably strayed from the teachings of Moses and Jesus."

That assumption is wrong since 'irredeemably strayed' is assuming, they are all not believers.  And Quran says that even Christians and Jews will go to paradise. [2:62](https://quran.com/2/62)

```
Indeed, those who believed and those who were Jews or Christians or 
Sabeans - those who believed in Allah and the Last Day and did 
righteousness - will have their reward with their Lord, and no 
fear will there be concerning them, nor will they grieve.
```

Please note that Allah did discriminate no group when He gave humanity the Quran. Logically speaking everyone can commit sins of another 'ethnic group', specially when muslims became christians or jews and so on.

### "However eagerly you may want them to, most men will not believe. You ask no reward from them for this: it is a reminder for all people"  ([12:103](https://quran.com/12/103), [12:104](https://quran.com/12/104))

Islam can mean `Peace accquired by Submiting yourself to Allah`, in that context, Quran is the ultimate vehicle for achieving that peace. It is the truth for the belivers and not an opinion.

## __________________________________

Note: I assume here that muslims are the most perfect form of believer (muslim can mean a person who submits to Allah). Many people of other ethnic groups can be muslims (and they don't know).

## When did the Jews/Christians go wrong?

#### When they do attribute partners/sons to God. (Shirk)

[6:100](https://quran.com/6/100)

```
But they have attributed to Allah partners - the jinn, while 
He has created them - and have fabricated for Him sons and 
daughters. Exalted is He and high above what they describe
```

[9:30](https://quran.com/9/30)

```
The Jews say, "Ezra is the son of Allah "; and the Christians 
say, "The Messiah is the son of Allah ." That is their 
statement from their mouths; they imitate the saying of those 
who disbelieved [before them]. May Allah destroy them; 
how are they deluded?
```

#### When they are declared enemies of the believers [5:82](https://quran.com/5/82)

```
You will surely find the most intense of the people in animosity 
toward the believers [to be] the Jews and those who associate others 
with Allah ; and you will find the nearest of them in affection to 
the believers those who say, "We are Christians." That is because 
among them are priests and monks and because they are not arrogant.
```

#### When they deliberated changed Allah words [2:75](https://quran.com/2/75)

```
Do you covet, that they would believe for you while a 
party of them used to hear the words of Allah and then distort the Torah after 
they had understood it while they were knowing?
```

#### When they intentionaly ignore Allah Messenger(s)

[2:101](https://quran.com/2/101)

```
And when a messenger from Allah came to them confirming that which was with them, 
a party of those who had been given the Scripture threw the Scripture of Allah 
behind their backs as if they did not know [what it contained].
```

[4:150](https://quran.com/4/150),[151](https://quran.com/4/151)

```
Indeed, those who disbelieve in Allah and His messengers and wish to
discriminate between Allah and His messengers and say, "We believe in 
some and disbelieve in others," and wish to adopt a way in between -
Those are the disbelievers, truly. And We have prepared for the disbelievers 
a humiliating punishment.
```

#### When they indeed say profanities about Jesus (as)  [5:78](https://quran.com/5/78)

(Targets Children of Israel)

```
Cursed were those who disbelieved among the Children of Israel by the 
tongue of David and of Jesus, the son of Mary. That was because they 
disobeyed and [habitually] transgressed.
```

#### When they have intimacy with idolaters/disbelivers [5:80](https://quran.com/5/80)

```
You see many of them becoming allies of those who disbelieved. 
How wretched is that which they have put forth for themselves 
in that Allah has become angry with them, and in the punishment 
they will abide eternally.
```

Note: Muslims have this [reminder](https://quran.com/5/51). (5:51)

#### They judge by what Allah didn't revealed to them  [5:44](https://quran.com/5/44)

```
Indeed, We sent down the Torah, in which was guidance and light. The 
prophets who submitted [to Allah ] judged by it for the Jews, as did 
the rabbis and scholars by that with which they were entrusted of the
Scripture of Allah, and they were witnesses thereto. So do not fear 
the people but fear Me, and do not exchange My verses for a small price. 
And whoever does not judge by what Allah has revealed - then it is 
those who are the disbelievers.
```